# Official Diplomacy sets, variations and where to buy

Tags: variants, diplomacy

[Diplomacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomacy_%28game%29) only seems to have one set [available to buy widely](http://goo.gl/s2kjz) that I am aware of, built by Gibson Games.

It's nothing special, an averagely constructed cardboard board with [plastic piece](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/371445/diplomacy)s.

Are there any other officaly distributed boxes available? Preferably available to order online.

There also lots of variations of Diplomacy [available online](http://www.diplom.org/Online/variants.html), have any of these made it 'into the wild'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [original Hasbro Edition](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/24037/avalon-hill-hasbro-edition) is probably the physically best edition ever made - much better than the [current](http://www.amazon.com/Avalon-Hill-221930000AVH-Diplomacy) US version with cardboard counters.

The other highly recommended edition is the 1992 [Deluxe Diplomacy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032O9REG) by Avalon Hill, which turns up very occasionally and very expensively on eBay.

The only professionally printed Dip variants I know of are Colonial Diplomacy and Machiavelli.

Comment: Would love to see pictures of the Deluxe Diplomacy set :)

Comment: Added a link to the Amazon.com page, but it doesn't have internal pics.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the following variants whilst doing a bit more digging at [Board Game Geek](http://boardgamegeek.com/):

The [Anniversary edition](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/442282/diplomacy) with metal pieces, an '[Asmodee](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/117882/diplomacy)' edition, a [German variant](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/79736/diplomacy) from the 70's and some amazing custom-built boards ([one](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/184079/diplomacy) & [two](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/519804/diplomacy) - shown below).

[image: Custom Diplomacy Board at GenCon Ind]

Answer (score 2):

The original has wooden pieces, not plastic. Blocks for the armies and flat pointed ovals for the fleets. But I haven't seen that in a while.

There have been versions in other languages (at least I know of a Dutch version).

Sorry no links.